# How to properly use an if-statement with the <option> tag?

Tags: php, html

So what I have is an array of things. The items in the array are put into a drop down with the  tag, nothing new or complicated about that but here's the (current working) code anyway:

```
<?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $role['id']; ?>"><?php echo $role['name']; ?></option>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Now what needs to happen, is that if the $role['name'] is "Basic", it should not be displayed. I have been trying (and googling) for this, and I have been unsuccessful. I didn't think it was that big of a deal.

Here's what I'm trying:

```
<?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
    <?php if(!$role['name'] == "Basic") { ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $role['id']; ?>"><?php echo $role['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

When I try that it doesn't add any fields to the drop down at all, so I'm obviously missing something here. Any tips would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How about: `if($role['name'] != "Basic")` ? I think `!role['name'] == "Basic"` evaluates to `false == "Basic"`. Btw you can use the alternative style for the `if` statement too.

Comment: $role["name"] == "Basic" then.. try `echo ($role["name"] == "Basic");` and see if it's true or false.

Comment: Ohhh, yes. Good call Felix. if you want to preserve the way you wrote it maybe try `if(!($role['name'] == "Basic")) {`

Comment: @Felix, I don't know why (probably because I'm tired) but I didn't think of doing != 

It is working now >_> I wish I could mark your answer as the answer, but it is overall very silly. Thanks anyhoo.

Comment: does the word Basic in the form actually have a capitol B ? Capitalization needs to be the same

Comment: No worries, these things happen :)

Comment: I guess it just goes on to show that sometimes only an extra pair of eyeballs will solve the issue. =]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your problem is with [*operator precedence* <sup>[docs]</sup>](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php):

```
!role['name'] == "Basic"
```

Assuming that `role['name']` is never empty or contains the string `"0"` (see [converting to boolean](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php)), this will be evaluated as

```
false == "Basic"
```

which is always `false`. Use `!=` instead or write `!(role['name'] == "Basic")`.

You can use the alternative style for the `if` statement too:

```
<?php foreach($roles as $role): ?>
    <?php if($role['name'] != "Basic"): ?>
        ...
    <?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Just a note on this answer, I was using the if-statements as seen on my question (instead of the if: endif) and I was getting weird behavior. Conditions were not being checked, it wasn't until I decided to try the endif format that it started behaving correctly. I know they're supposed to be equivalent, but just in case some googler stumbles into this question.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
foreach($roles as $role)
{
if($role['name'] != "Basic")
{
echo '<option value="'.$role['id'].'">'.$role['name'].'</option>';
}
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

use

```
<?php if($role['name'] != "Basic") { ?>
```

instead of

```
<?php if(!$role['name'] == "Basic") { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if()` is incorrect:

```
if(!$role['name'] == "Basic")
```

What you intended was probably this:

```
if($role['name'] != "Basic")
```